# Swift 2 syntax for Parse fetchAllIfNeededInBackground

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, swift2, pfobject

What is the syntax for PFObject's fetchAllIfNeededInBackground (with block) in Swift2.

The objective-c signature is:

`+ (void)fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:(nullable NSArray<PFObject *> *)objects block:(nullable PFArrayResultBlock)block;`

[Parse PFObject Documentation](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)fetchAllIfNeededInBackground:)

Can someone write a quick example that compiles in Swift 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-complete should fill it for you, if not, have you tried something like

```
PFObject.fetchAllIfNeededInBackground(<objects>) { (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

    }
```